# Small angle approximation for $\frac{1+\sin\theta}{5+3\tan\theta-4\cos\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

Please could somebody explain how the expression involving $\theta$ that $$\frac{1+\sin\theta}{5+3\tan\theta-4\cos\theta}$$ approximates to for small values of $\theta$ is $1-2\theta+4\theta^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute the first terms of the Taylor series of $\dfrac{1+\sin\theta}{5+3\tan\theta-4\cos\theta}$, and you will get $1-2\theta+4\theta^2$.

Comment: I am getting, $\frac{1+\theta}{1+3\theta}=(1+\theta)(1-3\theta+9\theta^2)=(1-2\theta+6\theta^2)$, which is wrong.

Comment: I can't comment on that since I don't know how you got it. But, yes, it is wrong. I did compute the first terms of the Taylor series.

Comment: I got it using first term of Taylor series as you said. $sin\theta=\theta, cos\theta=1,tan\theta=\theta$. Then using binomial expansion for denominator.

Comment: @Martund You have to retain the denominator's $\theta^2$ term, as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Approximate the numerator and denominator up to $\theta^2$ terms and get $$\frac{1+\theta+o(\theta^2)}{1+3\theta+2\theta^2+o(\theta^2)}=(1+\theta)(1-3\theta+7\theta^2)+o(\theta^2)=1-2\theta+4\theta^2+o(\theta^2).$$